# What's the proper way to safely discard stdin characters of variable length in C?

Tags: c, signals, stdin, alarm, fgets

I am working on some example code in a C text called "Headfirst C".  I wrote a practice application that demonstrates signal handling and after finishing the chapter decided to play around with it a bit.  I'm an engineer used to working in LabVIEW (high degree of concurrency and intuitive event handling functionality) so I am interested in using alarms and signal handlers to generate periodic events.  My question is this:

In the following sample code, what is the proper method or best practices for discarding a variable amount of user input that sits in stdin?  I have written this little app as a demo and a 3 second alarm triggers an annoying "howdy!" message to interrupt an fgets call.  The thing I have noticed, however, is that if the user is interrupted in the middle of typing, when he eventually does press enter any text entered (having been interrupted or not) will be echoed back.  I want to discard anything that was interrupted before the user pressed enter.

```
//Sample Program - Signal Handling & Alarms
//Header Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

//Function Declarations
//Handler Functions
void diediedie(int sig);
void howdy(int sig);
//Handler Register Function
int catchSignal(int signum, void(*handler)(int));

//Variable declarations
//Declare interrupted flags
static int interrupted = 0;

//Program entrypoint
int main() {

  //Register interrupt hander, catch errors
  if(catchSignal(SIGINT, diediedie) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not register interrupt handler");
    exit(2);
  }

  //Register alarm handler, catch errors
  if(catchSignal(SIGALRM, howdy) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not register alarm handler");
    exit(2);
  }

  //Create initial alarm trigger
  alarm(3);

  //Do something stupid while waiting for signals
  char name[30];
  printf("Enter your name: ");
  //Keep waiting for user input even if interrupted by alarm signal
  while(1) {
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);
    if(interrupted) {
      // reset interrupted flag
      interrupted = 0;
      // ***** ADD CODE TO DISCARD INTERRUPTED INPUT HERE ******
    }
    else {
      //echo user input and break out
      printf("Hello %s\n", name);
      break;
    }
  }

  //end program
  return 0;

}

//interrupt handler definition
void diediedie(int sig) {

  //write some stuff, exit program
  puts("Goodbye world!");
  exit(1);

}

//alarm handler definition
void howdy(int sig) {
  //set interrupted flag
  interrupted = 1;
  //write some annoying message
  puts("howdy!");
  //set another alarm trigger
  alarm(3);
  //**** COULD STDIN BE FLUSHED HERE? ****
}

//signal handler registration function definition
int catchSignal(int signum, void(*handler)(int)) {

  //register handler
  struct sigaction action;
  action.sa_handler = handler;
  sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
  action.sa_flags = 0;
  return sigaction(signum, &action, NULL);

}
```

Is the proper place to do this purge within the alarm handler?  Note the comments indicating my thoughts for proper code location.

I have considered the following:

```
while(getchar() != EOF) {}
```

I am also wondering, what happens while fgets is waiting for user input and SIGALRM is raised?  Is that function terminated?  I observe that if I don't include the while loop to check the interrupted flag and respond appropriately, the program will finish the fgets, dump some garbage on the screen (I assume the current state of stdin?) and end the program.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Maybe [`tcflush()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcflush.html), or maybe not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that works if the standard input is indeed a terminal.

Comment: This line `tcflush(fileno(stdin), TCIFLUSH);` does seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix, a signal handler occurs out of band with your code.  If the signal occurs in the middle of a blocking system call, the system call will exit with `errno` set to EINTR.  But I believe that `fgets()` is handling this interruption for you and continuing on without returning control to you.

If you are using a Unix based OS and typing in input from the command line, what's really going on here is that you are reading data from your terminal in cooked mode.   Your program doesn't get any data from the TTY until return is pressed.  You need to set the terminal into 'raw' mode.  Here is an example of how to do that integrated with your code:

```
//Sample Program - Signal Handling & Alarms
//Header Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>

//Function Declarations
//Handler Functions
void diediedie(int sig);
void howdy(int sig);
//Handler Register Function
int catchSignal(int signum, void(*handler)(int));

//Variable declarations
//Declare interrupted sa_flags
static int interrupted = 0;

static struct termios save_termios;

//Program entrypoint
int main() {

  struct termios buf;
  int fd = 1;

  // This is derived from from Stevens, "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"
  if (tcgetattr(fd, &save_termios) < 0) /* get the original state */
        return -1;

  buf = save_termios;

  buf.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
                    /* echo off, canonical mode off, extended input
                       processing off, signal chars off */

  buf.c_iflag |= BRKINT | ICRNL;
                    /* SIGINT on BREAK, CR-toNL on */

  buf.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
                    /* clear size bits, parity checking off */

  buf.c_cflag |= CS8;
                    /* set 8 bits/char */

  buf.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
                    /* output processing off */

  buf.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;  /* 1 byte at a time */
  buf.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* no timer on input */

  if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &buf) < 0)
    return -1;


  //Register interrupt hander, catch errors
  if(catchSignal(SIGINT, diediedie) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not register interrupt handler");
    exit(2);
  }

  //Register alarm handler, catch errors
  if(catchSignal(SIGALRM, howdy) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not register alarm handler");
    exit(2);
  }

  //Create initial alarm trigger
  alarm(3);

  //Do something stupid while waiting for signals
  char name[30];
  printf("Enter your name: ");

  //Keep waiting for user input even if interrupted by alarm signal
  char nextchar = 0;
  char *p;
  p = name;
  while(nextchar != '\n') {
    nextchar = fgetc(stdin);
    if (interrupted) {
      // reset interrupted flag
      interrupted = 0;

      //Discard interrupted input by reseting 'p' to the start of the buffer
      p = name;
      *p = 0;
      continue;
    }
    if (nextchar == '\n') {
      *p = 0;
      fputc('\r', stdout);
      fputc('\n', stdout);
      break;
    }
    // You'll have to handle some characters manually to emulate what the
    // terminal does, or you could filter them out using a function like isprint() 
    // 
    if (nextchar == 127) {
      // *** handle backspace
      if (p > name) {
        p--;
      }
      // TODO: To handle this right you'll have to backup the cursor on the screen
    }  else {
      *p = nextchar;
      p++;
    }
    fputc(nextchar, stdout);

    // Handle buffer overflow
    if (p-name == sizeof(name) - 1) {
      *p = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  // echo user input
  printf("Input is: %s\r\n", name);
  tcsetattr(1, TCSAFLUSH, &save_termios);
}

//interrupt handler definition
void diediedie(int sig) {

  //write some stuff, exit program
  puts("Goodbye world!");

  tcsetattr(1, TCSAFLUSH, &save_termios);
  exit(1);

}

//alarm handler definition
void howdy(int sig) {
  //set interrupted flag
  interrupted = 1;
  //write some annoying message
  puts("howdy!");
  //set another alarm trigger
  alarm(3);
}

// signal handler registration function definition
int catchSignal(int signum, void(*handler)(int)) {

  //register handler
  struct sigaction action;
  action.sa_handler = handler;
  sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
  action.sa_flags = 0;
  return sigaction(signum, &action, NULL);
}
```

Note that you need to save the original terminal settings and restore them before the program exits!  If you get into trouble, you might break the terminal settings. Use `reset` or `stty sane` from the command line to restore sane terminal settings. For more information on the termios datastructure, see the man pages.

You can also use libraries like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) to handle raw input.

Answer (score 1):

To do this right, you'd need to put the terminal into "raw" mode, in which every keystroke is returned immediately to the application, instead of being accumulated with interpretation of line-editing characters ("cooked" mode, which is the default).

Of course, if you don't let the kernel handle line-editing (backspace, for example), then you need to do it yourself, which is quite a lot of work. Interpreting backspace and whatever other editing commands you're interested in isn't that hard, but maintaining the correct appearance on the terminal is a pain.

See `man termios` for a lot more information.

Comment: Using termios I was able to solve it like this: `tcflush(fileno(stdin), TCIFLUSH);`

However, I understand this only works for terminal applications?  I also did not change anything I was doing at the terminal (still 'cooked' mode I think) so does this solution have any implications I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Kin3TiX: The main problem is a race condition which will show up under load. You're relying on luck to keep the action of `tcflush` synchronized with what the user sees in the console; if the `tcflush` is delayed, it will delete characters which were apparently typed after the interruption. IMHO, flushing the input queue is a horrible thing to do to your users; if you're going to do it, you should at least ensure that the result is obvious.